Agregar un campo a finalizar compra mediante block de Guttenberg
Necesito agregar un campo de DNI al Checkout block nuevo de woocommerce mediente guttenber. Logre agregarlo editando el archivo woocommerce/src/Blocks/Domain/Services/CheckoutFieldsAdmin.php (activo) pero no logro hacer que se refleje en la factura.



y como lo pasas a la factura???

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
